# Why don't I have permission to write to app dir on external storage?

Tags: android, file-permissions, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

The TL;DR question summary: My Android app tries to **write** to the app's **external storage directory** on an SD card. It fails with a **permissions error**. But the same code (method), extracted into a minimal test app, succeeds!

Since our target API level includes KitKat and later (as well as JellyBean), and KitKat restricts apps from writing anywhere on the SD card except the app's designated external storage directory, the app tries to write to that designated directory, `/path/to/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files`. I verify this directory's path by getting a list of directories from `Activity.getExternalFilesDirs(null);` and finding one that `isRemovable()`. I.e. we're not hard-coding the path to the SD card, because it varies by manufacturer and device. Here is code that demonstrates the problem:

```java
// Attempt to create a test file in dir.
private void testCreateFile(File dir) {
    Log.d(TAG, ">> Testing dir " + dir.getAbsolutePath());

    if (!checkDir(dir)) { return; }

    // Now actually try to create a file in this dir.
    File f = new File(dir, "foo.txt");
    try {
        boolean result = f.createNewFile();
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Attempted to create file. No errors. Result: %b. Now exists: %b",
                result, f.exists()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create file " + f.getAbsolutePath(), e);
    }
}
```

The checkDir() method is not as relevant, but I'll include it here for completeness. It just makes sure the directory is on removable storage that is mounted, and logs other properties of the directory (exists, writable).

```java
private boolean checkDir(File dir) {
    boolean isRemovable = false;
    // Can't tell whether it's removable storage?
    boolean cantTell = false;
    String storageState = null;

    // Is this the primary external storage directory?
    boolean isPrimary = false;
    try {
        isPrimary = dir.getCanonicalPath()
                .startsWith(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getCanonicalPath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        isPrimary = dir.getAbsolutePath()
                .startsWith(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    }

    if (isPrimary) {
        isRemovable = Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable();
        storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // I actually use a try/catch for IllegalArgumentException here, but 
        // that doesn't affect this example.
        isRemovable = Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(dir);
        storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState(dir);
    } else {
        cantTell = true;
    }

    if (cantTell) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("  exists: %b  readable: %b  writeable: %b primary: %b  cantTell: %b",
                dir.exists(), dir.canRead(), dir.canWrite(), isPrimary, cantTell));
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("  exists: %b  readable: %b  writeable: %b primary: %b  removable: %b  state: %s  cantTell: %b",
                dir.exists(), dir.canRead(), dir.canWrite(), isPrimary, isRemovable, storageState, cantTell));
    }

    return (cantTell || (isRemovable && storageState.equalsIgnoreCase(MEDIA_MOUNTED)));
}
```

In the test app (running on Android 5.1.1), the following log output shows that the code is working fine:

```
10-25 19:56:40 D/MainActivity: >> Testing dir /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.example.testapp/files
10-25 19:56:40 D/MainActivity:   exists: true  readable: true  writeable: true primary: false  removable: true  state: mounted  cantTell: false
10-25 19:56:40 D/MainActivity: Attempted to create file. No errors. Result: false. Now exists: true
```

So the file was created successfully. But in my actual app (also running on Android 5.1.1), the call to `createNewFile()` fails with a permissions error:

```
10-25 18:14:56... D/LessonsDB: >> Testing dir /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files
10-25 18:14:56... D/LessonsDB:   exists: true  readable: true  writeable: true primary: false  removable: true  state: mounted  cantTell: false
10-25 18:14:56... E/LessonsDB: Failed to create file /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files/foo.txt
    java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:941)
        at com.example.myapp.dmm.LessonsDB.testCreateFile(LessonsDB.java:169)
    ...
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:934)
    ...
```

Before you mark this as a duplicate: I have read through several other questions on SO describing permission failures when writing to an SD card under KitKat or later. But none of the causes or solutions given seem to apply to this situation:

- The device is **not** connected as **mass storage**. I double-checked. However, MTP is on. (I can't turn it off without unplugging the USB cable that I use for viewing the logs.)
- My **manifest** includes `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
- I'm targeting API level 22, so I shouldn't have to **request** permission at run-time (a la **Marshmallow**). The build.gradle has `targetSdkVersion 22` (and `buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'`, `compileSdkVersion 23`).
- I'm running on KitKat and Lollipop; I don't even have a Marshmallow device. So again, I shouldn't have to request permission at runtime, even if I were targeting API level 23.
- As mentioned above, I'm writing to the **designated external storage directory** that's supposed to be writeable by my app, even on KitKat.
- The external storage is **mounted**; the code verifies this.

Summary of when it works and when it doesn't:

- On my pre-KitKat device, both the test app and the real app work fine. They successfully create a file in the app dir on the SD card.
- On my KitKat and Lollipop devices, the test app works fine but the real app doesn't. Instead it shows the error in the above log.

What difference is there between the test app and the real app? Well, obviously the real app has a lot more stuff in it. But I can't see anything that should matter. Both have identical `compileSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, etc. Both are also using `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'` as a dependency.

Comment: Did you add ``<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`` ??

Comment: @DonaldWu: Yes, see the 2nd bullet point.

Comment: @LarsH a long shot, but worth trying. You did mention adding the respective `uses-permission` declaration. Now, is it declared in the right place in the "real app"? As in, is it OUTSIDE the `application` element in the manifest file?

Comment: @Leo: Thanks for checking. Yes, it is outside (and before) the `<application>` element.

Comment: Downvoter, please comment as to how the question could be improved.

Comment: "It just makes sure the directory is on removable storage that is mounted, and logs other properties of the directory (exists, writable)" -- FWIW, I would not trust your `isPrimary` logic. Also note that `getExternalFilesDirs()` will not return separate removable storage volumes prior to Android 4.4. Most apps should simply ignore removable storage prior to Android 4.4. "My manifest includes <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />" -- that is not necessary for any of the locations pointed to by `getExternalFilesDirs()` on Android 4.4+.

Comment: In terms of your problem, do a full uninstall of the failing app (e.g., `adb uninstall`, or remove from Settings). Make sure this directory was removed from the removable storage. Install and run your app again, and see if it behaves better now.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Looks like uninstalling the app and making sure the directory was removed did the trick! I may have created that directory myself, and failed to set up permissions somewhere?? Thank you! If you create an answer, I'll have somewhere to award the bounty. But it would be helpful to figure out how to avoid this problem in the future ... It would be helpful to be able to create the directory before the app is installed, and I don't want to mess up permissions in doing so.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Re: `isPrimary`, I wouldn't totally trust it if `getCanonicalPath()` throws an exception, since there could be more than one path to the primary external storage (thanks to symbolic links, for example). Is there another reason not to trust it? Is there a way to improve it, that works pre-Lollipop? The only reason I use `isPrimary` is that you can't pass a path to `isExternalStorageRemovable()` or `getExternalStorageState()` before Lollipop.

Comment: @CommonsWare: "`getExternalFilesDirs()` will not return separate removable storage volumes prior to Android 4.4" - from the docs I'm looking at, `getExternalFilesDirs()` isn't available prior to Android 4.4 (API level 19). So I'm not sure what you mean. "Most apps should simply ignore removable storage prior to Android 4.4." I don't doubt you're right. Unfortunately that's not an option for us ... our app is all about removable storage, and probably over half our users are pre-4.4. P.S. thanks for looking into this Question.

Comment: @LarsH: "So I'm not sure what you mean" -- sorry, I was thinking of `ActivityCompat`, which has a backwards-compatible `getExternalFilesDirs()` that returns a one-element list all the time on 4.3 and older.

Comment: @CommonsWare: ' "My manifest includes <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />" -- that is not necessary for any of the locations pointed to by getExternalFilesDirs() on Android 4.4+.' -- so I could probably add an `android:maxSdkVersion="18"` on that uses-permission.

Comment: @LarsH: Correct. That scenario is pretty much the reason they added `android:maxSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've learned more about this issue, and it's different enough from CommonsWare's answer that I think it's worth a new answer.

- What made the difference for my original scenario was the SD cards: If a card *already had* a `/Android/data/com.example.myapp` folder on it that was *not created on this phone*, then the app might have trouble getting permission to write to that folder. Whereas if the folder did not exist, the app could create it, and write to it. At least in KitKat and later.

  - This is supported by something explained in [this article](https://www.xda-developers.com/diving-into-sdcardfs-how-googles-fuse-replacement-will-reduce-io-overhead/):

    > ... starting with API Level 19 [KitKat], READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE was no longer required to access files located on external storage – provided the **data folder created by the FUSE daemon** matches the app’s package name. FUSE would handle **synthesizing the owner, group, and modes of files** on external storage **when an application is installed** [emphasis added].
  - So this confirms the guess that the problem arose because I created the app's data folder manually, instead of letting Android set it up as it needed. Future research: Instead of looking only to app permissions like WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, also check the user, group, and mode settings of the app's data folder on the filesystem: both when created manually, and when created by app installation. Compare & contrast! Maybe this will provide enough information to allow the app's data folder to be created manually and still work. Keep in mind that there is a wrapper / emulation layer over the FAT32 filesystem of the SD card, so we need to consider both filesystem layers.
- In a later scenario, I found that it's necessary for the app to call `context.getExternalFilesDirs(null)` in order for the `/Android/data/com.example.myapp` folder to be created on the SD card. (At least, on Android 5.1 Lollipop and later. Need to test that on KitKat.)

Answer (score 8):

Since one app worked and another didn't, the difference was between the apps, not with the device or card. The directory in question does not require any Android permissions (e.g., `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`). The only reason why you would not be able to write to it would be if the Android system had not set up the filesystem permissions properly.

> I may have created that directory myself, and failed to set up permissions somewhere?

I am not certain that you can create that directory yourself from outside the app and have it work. Ideally that would be fine, but I have not tried it and I can see where that might pose problems.

> Is there another reason not to trust it?

Given the filesystem shenanigans that are going on, I get very nervous when developers make assumptions regarding the nature of paths, that's all.

Comment: I'm going to award the bounty to this answer, unless someone comes up with a better one soon. This answer has already given me a breakthrough. My criterion for a better answer would be one that tells me how to create and populate the app directory on the SD card ahead of time (i.e. before the app is installed on any phone) or gives a reliable reference that such a thing isn't possible.

Comment: @LarsH: I doubt that you will find a reliable reference as to whether this is possible or not.

Comment: For the clarity of the record, for future readers: It's true that one *app* worked and another didn't (on the same device and card); but it's also true that one *device* worked and another didn't (for the same app), and that one *card* worked and another didn't (for the same app). It turned out the difference was in the cards: on one card, the app directory for the real app (but not the test app) had been created beforehand, manually; while on another card (in another device), both of the app directories were created automatically by Android. That's the best I can tell, anyway.