# Permission Granted Still App crashes in Marshmllow

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating an app for downloading files to my phone. The app is working fine in devices less than 23 but getting crashed in SDK > 23 devices. I had successfully granted the permission on run-time. But still making the app crash during downloading files.

Permission.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
           Toast.makeText(Permission.this,
                   "Build Version Less than 23", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
       }
       else if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
               == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           Toast.makeText(Permission.this,
           "Permission Already Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
           status = 1;
       } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"}, this.REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == this.REQUEST_CODE && grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(Permission.this,
                    "Permission Granted Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(Permission.this,
                    "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

So the app is asking permission fine and I successfully granted it. But during downloading, I am getting this log.

--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-153
                  Process: us.browserapp.manager, PID: 2898
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                      at us.browserapp.manager.get.DownloadManagerImpl$Initializer.run(DownloadManagerImpl.java:210)
                   Caused by: java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                      at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
                      at us.browserapp.manager.get.DownloadManagerImpl$Initializer.run(DownloadManagerImpl.java:202)
                   Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                      at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                      at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                      at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:932)
                      at us.browserapp.manager.get.DownloadManagerImpl$Initializer.run(DownloadManagerImpl.java:202) 
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae70c540
E/ActivityThread: Activity us.browserapp.manager.ui.main.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection us.browserapp.manager.ui.main.MainActivity$1@73e5314 that was originally bound here
                  android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity us.browserapp.manager.ui.main.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection us.browserapp.manager.ui.main.MainActivity$1@73e5314 that was originally bound here
                      at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:1092)
                      at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:986)
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1303)
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1286)
                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:604)
                      at us.browserapp.manager.ui.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:104)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
E/ActivityThread: Activity us.browserapp.manager.ui.main.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection us.browserapp.manager.ui.fragment.MissionsFragment$1@961c89d that was originally bound here
                  android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity us.browserapp.manager.ui.main.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection us.browserapp.manager.ui.fragment.MissionsFragment$1@961c89d that was originally bound here
                      at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:1092)
                      at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:986)
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1303)
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1286)
                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:604)
                      at us.browserapp.manager.ui.fragment.MissionsFragment.onCreateView(MissionsFragment.java:71)
                      at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2898 SIG: 9
Application terminated.

DownloadManagerImpl.java

```
public class DownloadManagerImpl implements DownloadManager
{
    private static final String TAG = DownloadManagerImpl.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;
    private String mLocation;
    protected ArrayList<DownloadMission> mMissions = new ArrayList<DownloadMission>();

    public DownloadManagerImpl(Context context, String location) {
        mContext = context;
        mLocation = location;
        loadMissions();
    }

    @Override
    public int startMission(String url, String name, int threads) {
        DownloadMission mission = new DownloadMission();
        mission.url = url;
        mission.name = name;
        mission.location = mLocation;
        mission.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mission.threadCount = threads;
        new Initializer(mContext, mission).start();
        return insertMission(mission);
    }

    @Override
    public void resumeMission(int i) {
        DownloadMission d = getMission(i);
        if (!d.running && d.errCode == -1) {
            d.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void pauseMission(int i) {
        DownloadMission d = getMission(i);
        if (d.running) {
            d.pause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteMission(int i) {
        getMission(i).delete();
        mMissions.remove(i);
    }

    private void loadMissions() {
        File f = new File(mLocation);

        if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) {
            File[] subs = f.listFiles();

            for (File sub : subs) {
                if (sub.isDirectory()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (sub.getName().endsWith(".fdm")) {
                    String str = Utility.readFromFile(sub.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (str != null && !str.trim().equals("")) {

                        if (DEBUG) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "loading mission " + sub.getName());
                            Log.d(TAG, str);
                        }

                        DownloadMission mis = new Gson().fromJson(str, DownloadMission.class);

                        if (mis.finished) {
                            sub.delete();
                            continue;
                        }

                        mis.running = false;
                        mis.recovered = true;
                        insertMission(mis);
                    }
                } else if (!sub.getName().startsWith(".") && !new File(sub.getPath() + ".fdm").exists()) {
                    // Add a dummy mission for downloaded files
                    DownloadMission mis = new DownloadMission();
                    mis.length = sub.length();
                    mis.done = mis.length;
                    mis.finished = true;
                    mis.running = false;
                    mis.name = sub.getName();
                    mis.location = mLocation;
                    mis.timestamp = sub.lastModified();
                    insertMission(mis);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public DownloadMission getMission(int i) {
        return mMissions.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mMissions.size();
    }

    private int insertMission(DownloadMission mission) {
        int i = -1;

        DownloadMission m = null;

        if (mMissions.size() > 0) {
            do {
                m = mMissions.get(++i);
            } while (m.timestamp > mission.timestamp && i < mMissions.size() - 1);

            //if (i > 0) i--;
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }

        mMissions.add(i, mission);

        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLocation() {
        return mLocation;
    }

    private class Initializer extends Thread {
        private Context context;
        private DownloadMission mission;

        public Initializer(Context context, DownloadMission mission) {
            this.context = context;
            this.mission = mission;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(mission.url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                mission.length = conn.getContentLength();

                if (mission.length <= 0) {
                    mission.errCode = DownloadMission.ERROR_SERVER_UNSUPPORTED;
                    //mission.notifyError(DownloadMission.ERROR_SERVER_UNSUPPORTED);
                    return;
                }

                // Open again
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + (mission.length - 10) + "-" + mission.length);

                if (conn.getResponseCode() != 206) {
                    // Fallback to single thread if no partial content support
                    mission.fallback = true;

                    if (DEBUG) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "falling back");
                    }
                }

                if (DEBUG) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "response = " + conn.getResponseCode());
                }

                mission.blocks = mission.length / BLOCK_SIZE;

                if (mission.threadCount > mission.blocks) {
                    mission.threadCount = (int) mission.blocks;
                }

                if (mission.threadCount <= 0) {
                    mission.threadCount = 1;
                }

                if (mission.blocks * BLOCK_SIZE < mission.length) {
                    mission.blocks++;
                }


                new File(mission.location).mkdirs();
                new File(mission.location + "/" + mission.name).createNewFile();
                RandomAccessFile af = new RandomAccessFile(mission.location + "/" + mission.name, "rw");
                af.setLength(mission.length);
                af.close();

                mission.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Notify
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any Idea about what is going on? I have lost nearly 3 days on this. NB: App is working superfine in Lollipop devices.

Comment: Did you add read permission?

just add read permission and check :)

Comment: In manifest? Or should I add in runtime?

Comment: This may help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40252541/why-dont-i-have-permission-to-write-to-app-dir-on-external-storage

Comment: What is inside mLocation?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the fact that you are trying to create a directory using an invalid path. For example, this can happen if you attempt to create a directory in a place you don't have permission to do so. If that is the case, the call to `mkdirs` will fail and the subsequent call to `createNewFile` will throw an exception since the directory was never actually created.

Comment: @DroidGenie I would add a call to `File.exists()` between the call to `mkdirs` and `createNewFile` to see if the directory was created successfully. If not, you should inspect the value of `mission.location` and check that it represents a valid path.